# What is the most effective way to get children at index in React

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

Assume a `Component` that I want to access to the 3nd child.

```
<Component>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
</Component>
```

Actually, I found 3 ways to do that:

**1) With React.children.map**

```
const Component = ({children}) => 
  <>{React.Children.map(children, (child, i) => i === 2 && child)}</>
```

Works fine but is verbose and in *O(n)*.

**2) With React.Children.toArray**

```
const Component = ({children}) =>
  <>{React.Children.toArray(children)[2]}</>
```

Less verbose but I don't know about the complexity. Is it *O(1)* ? And if so, is it performant enough ?

**3) Direclty use children as an array**

```
const Component = ({children}) => <>{children[2]}</>
```

At first glance it seems ideal but it won't work fine if children are passed as an array. Example, if I wrote something like this:

```
<Component>
  <div>1</div>      
  {[2, 3].map(i => <div key={i}>{i}</div>)}
</Component>
```

`Component` will assume to have only 2 children whose 2nd is an array of 2 children. Therefore `children[2]` won't exist.

So my question is: What is the best way to get children at index ? Is method `toArray` more efficient than `map` ? Or is there a way to fix the issue of the **3)** option ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is not much difference between using `toArray` or `map` method from `React.Children`. Below are the respective code snippets from the React codebase

```
function toArray(children) {
  const result = [];
  mapIntoWithKeyPrefixInternal(children, result, null, child => child);
  return result;
}

function mapChildren(children, func, context) {
  if (children == null) {
    return children;
  }
  const result = [];
  mapIntoWithKeyPrefixInternal(children, result, null, func, context);
  return result;
}
```

As you see, if you pass the children as null or if you don't pass any children, `React.Children.map` will return you null or undefined respectively. However in any such case, toArray will always return you an array, so you can safely use `<>{React.Children.toArray(children)[3]}</>`

Also when you use

```
<>{React.Children.map(children, (child, i) => i === 2 && child)}</>
```

it return you `[false, false, Object]` which isn't what you intent. You could however write

```
<>{React.Children.map(children, (child, i) => i === 2 ? child: null)}</>
```

Comment: Didn't notice the `[false, false, Object]` return by `map`. Thanks

Comment: So is there no way to get an element at an index without iterating through all?

Comment: @frontsidebus You can simply use `children[i]` for that